# C and C++ Cross Compiling from Arch Linux to Windows

Tags: c++, g++, cross-compiling

I can't install **mingw-w64-gcc** in **Arch linux**, so i can't compile my `.cpp` files for Windows...
I have aldready tried **wineg++**, but it isn't good for me...
Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you install **mingw-w64-gcc**?, do you know how to install packages for the AUR?

Comment: Yes I know how to do it, but I can't find mingw-w64-gcc on AUR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is to install **mingw-w64-gcc** in Arch, the steps you need to do are:

1) go to: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-gcc/ and download a snapshot (on the upper right side of the web page).

2) decompress the file with `tar xzvf /your_path/mingw-w64-gcc.tar.gz`.

3) install the package. `cd mingw-w64-gcc/ && makepkg -si`.

You may need to install other dependencies from the Arch User Repository (AUR).

Hope you find this helpful.

For future questions related with Arch Linux issues I would recommend you first to search in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/), and if you cannot find a solution, then use the [Arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/).

PS: Let me also suggest you to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for making your code executable anywhere. It's quite simple to use when you learn it.

Comment: In this case, please consider to accept the answer! thank you!